# Python : I have a small bug with my beginner calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

I've just started with python and I'm not too great at learning where the problems lie. I have  this calculator code which I am trying to create from scratch, however I've run into a small problem.

```
def Addition():
    print('Addition: What are your numbers?')
    a = int(input('First Number:'))
    b = int(input('Second Number:'))
    print('Your Answer is:', a + b)


def Subtraction():
    print('Subtraction: What are your numbers?')
    c = int(input('First Number:'))
    d = int(input('Second Number:'))
    print('Your Answer is:', c - d)


def Multiplication():
    print('Multiplication: What are your numbers?')
    e = int(input('First Number:'))
    f = int(input('Second Number:'))
    print('Your Answer is:', e * f)


def Division():
    print('Division: What are your numbers?')
    g = int(input('First Number:'))
    h = int(input('Second Number:'))
    print('Your Answer is:', g / h)

x = 'test'


def Question():
        x = input('What would you like to do? (Add, Subtract, Divide, Multiply or         Quit)')
        while x == 'Add' or 'add' or 'A' or 'a':
            x = 'test123'
            print(Addition())
            x = 'test'
        while x == 'Divide' or 'Div' or 'D' or 'divide' or 'div':
            x = 'test'
            print(Division())
            x = 'test'
        while x == 'Multiply' or 'Mul' or 'Mult' or 'multiply' or 'mult' or 'Times' or 'times':
            x = 'test'
            print(Multiplication())
            x = 'test'
        while x == 'Subtract' or 'Take Away' or 'Take away' or 'take Away' or 'take away':
            x = 'test'
            print(Subtraction())
            x = 'test'
        while x == 'Quit' or 'exit' or 'quit' or 'Exit':
            x = 'test'
            print(exit())
        while x == 'test':
            print(Question())


while x == 'test':
        print(Question())
```

When i run the code it decides that Addition() is what it wants to run after asking me the question, no matter the input. Is this because I have defined it first, or for some other reason? Also, I don't want to use anyone elses code, but is there a simpler way to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: I think I might scrap this and start again after I have leant a bit more about python :). Then i might make a button input... if that's possible. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
    while x == 'Add' or 'add' or 'A' or 'a':
```

Which should probably be:

```
    if x in ['Add', 'add', 'A', 'a']:
```

And then make the other ones elif statements.

Comment: Sweet, worked exactly as i wanted it to! Would there be a way to do it without int()?

Comment: You don't need the int() part, just use input(). It will crash if the user types a non-number, but that would also be the case if you used int(). You need to catch exceptions for that as well.

Comment: when i run Division() without int() i get the TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'. Any way to sort this?

Comment: Sorry, your absolutely right. You might be better off using float() instead of int()

Comment: Thanks for that, i completely forgot about float()! I hate being a beginner :)

Comment: According to http://docs.python.org/3.2/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations, the test would could be better written as `if x in {'Add', 'add', 'A', 'a'}:`. An even better solution may be to write `if 'add'.startswith(x.lower()):`.

Answer (score 3):

There's multiple things wrong with your code, but the reason why your `Addition` function is always executed is because comparing strings doesn#t work the way you think it does. When you write

```
while x == 'Add' or 'add' or 'A' or 'a':
```

this is interpreted as

```
while (x == 'Add') or 'add' or 'A' or 'a':
```

and thus checks if x equals 'Add' or any of the string literals evaluate to 'True', which they do. A better way to write the comparison would be using the `in` operator (and use an `if` statement and not a while):

```
if x.lower() in ["add", "a"]:
```

Calling `lower` on the String transforms it to all lowercase characters, so comparing it to 'add' is sufficient and you don't need to compare it to any other spelling which just differs in case.

Another thing to note is that you have a huge amount of unneccesary repetition in your code - you could refactor away the input part to a separate function instead of copypasting the code four times:

```
def getInput():
    a = int(input('First Number:'))
    b = int(input('Second Number:'))
    return a, b
```

You can now write your functions like this:

```
def addition():
    print('Addition: What are your numbers?')
    a, b = getInput()
    print('Your Answer is:', a + b)
```

Or you could simplify this even further by creating a generalized evaluation function which takes a function as an Argument which is applied to the input values:

```
def evaluate(name, function):
    print("%s: What are your numbers?" % name)
    a, b = getInput()
    print("Your Answer is:", function(a, b))
```

This allows you to define addition, multiplication etc. in terms of the 'evaluate' function, passing a lambda as an argument:

```
evaluate("Addition", lambda x, y: x + y)
evaluate("Multiplication", lambda x, y: x * y)
evaluate("Two times a to the power of b", lambda x, y: 2 * (x ** y))
```

Comment: the only reason there was a while is because i couldn't figure out the if statements, but now i understand them a lot more! What exactly does x.lower() do? Not being rude, just curious :)

Comment: The `lower` function call transforms the string to lowercase; so it's enough to compare it to 'add' and you don't need to worry about alternate spellings which only differ in case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to read about functions and function parameters. Also have a look at loops and their usage.

Here is a refactored version of your code. It's not perfect, but it should give you an idea where to move.

```
def addition(a, b):
    return a + b


def subtraction(a, b):
    return a - b


def multiplication(a, b):
    return a * b


def division(a, b):
    if b != 0:
        return a / b
    else:
        print("Error: division by zero")


def question():
        x = input('What would you like to do? (Add, Subtract, Divide, Multiply or Quit)')
        while x != "Quit":
            a = int(input("Enter number a: "))
            b = int(input("Enter number b: "))

            if x == "Add":
                print(addition(a,b))
            elif x == "Subtract":
                print(subtraction(a,b))
            elif x == "Divide":
                print(division(a,b))
            elif x == "Multiply":
                print(multiplication(a,b))
            else:
                print("Wrong operation")

            x = input('What would you like to do? (Add, Subtract, Divide, Multiply or Quit)')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    question()
```

And here is how you would use it after running:

```
What would you like to do? (Add, Subtract, Divide, Multiply or Quit)"Add"
Enter number a: 4
Enter number b: 5
9
What would you like to do? (Add, Subtract, Divide, Multiply or Quit)"Subtract"
Enter number a: 6
Enter number b: 3
3
What would you like to do? (Add, Subtract, Divide, Multiply or Quit)"Quit"
```